# 404 Conky-Manager difficulty's with Ubuntu

Tags: networking, apt, 20.04, gnome, conky

Recently tried installing the conky manager for widgets I cam across a forum saying to try these 3 commands

first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
```

and with this first one I get this error message I have no clue what means:

```
404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Ign:11 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release.gpg
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tista/adapta/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
```

It seems to be a networking issue but I am fully connected and secured if anyone knows it would be a great help thanks.

Comment: It should be easy to understand that (1) the error message has nothing to do with the last added PPA, that (2) neither of the PPAs mentioned in the error message has content (can't work) for Ubuntu 20.04 and (3) that they need to be removed should be obvious.

Comment: whats your way to solve this issue? @ChanganAuto

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @N0rbert Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: @Loganaruto Point #3 above. Just open Software & Updates > Other software and you'll find all the 3rd party PPAs. Remove the ones mentioned in the error message and **avoid adding PPAs / blindly following random guides unless you confirm that they work for your specific release**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tomtomtom PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Etomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/conky-manager?field.series_filter=focal) which provide Conky Manager for 20.04 LTS:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tomtomtom/conky-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install conky-manager
# or # sudo apt-get install conky-manager2
```

Removal or currently added wrong repositories is possible by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:tista/adapta
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me